# iOS FBConnect access_token and resuming

Tags: iphone, objective-c, iphone-sdk-3.0, fbconnect

I am using FBConnect in my iOS app, with the latest version of FBConnect-iOS.

The github docs claim that no "resume" function is available for fbconnect sessions because the developer is not responsible for storing the `access_token` information. [Link Here](https://github.com/facebook/facebook-ios-sdk/wiki/Home/12b6e20cb7366a6f364c683822b8dbd2749bc8ed)

This is all well and good, and I can grab the access_token string using  `[_facebook access_token];` however, I can't figure out how to resume a session using this token so the user doesn't have to login every time the app is opened.

Does anyone know how to resume a session using the `access_token` key?

Many thanks!
Brett

Answer (score 0):

Just call [_facebook isSessionValid] the function to check the session.